# useState on array of input values removes focus

Tags: react-hooks

Im using the `useState` hook to update an array. This array renders a list of inputs.

This code does update the `useState` hook correctly but it removes focus from the input after every key press. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Todos = () => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState(["Read book", "Tidy room"]);

    function update(index: number, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        const newTodos = [...todos];
        newTodos[index] = event.target.value;
        setTodos(newTodos);
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {todos.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={item}>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={item}
                            onChange={event => update(index, event)}
                        />
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default Exercises;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem is that you're using the item's value as the `key` for each `<li>`.  When you change the value in the input, the key will change and react renders an entire new `<li>` instead of just changing the one that is already loaded on the screen.

The easiest solution would be to make each Todo an object, and give it a  `id` that doesn't change:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface Todo {
  value: string;
  id: string;
}

const Todos = () => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([
      { 
        value: "Read book",
        id: '1'
      }, 
      {
        value: "Tidy room",
        id: '2'
      }
    ]);

    function update(index: number, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        const newTodos = [...todos];
        newTodos[index].value = event.target.value;
        setTodos(newTodos);
    }

    return (
        <ul>
            {todos.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={item.value}
                            onChange={event => update(index, event)}
                        />
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default Exercises;
```

Comment: I cant add an ID in this way however I could use the index in the todos's array as the key. Not sure if there are potential issues with this approach though?